# Using Presto with custom SQL like DSL

Tags: dsl, presto

My web application shall obtain insights over parquet files stored on data lake with using custom SQL like DSL. Now I use Spark for transforming this DSL commands into DataFrame API but I realise that it's possible to achieve better performance with using MPP solutions like Presto\Impala etc. as they always have a prepared process for SQL execution. But I have a limitation - transforming DSL to SQL should be done some third party place. I'm aware that I can build a proxy app for transforming from this DSL to SQL. My question is the next: is there any way to make this transformation on Presto's side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any way to make this transformation on Presto's side?

Presto does not have any extension points for *language*, so it does not allow to replace SQL or extend it by a plugin.

Of course, you can roll your mini-language replacing SQL parser and analyzer in Presto, but this will be a lot of work. If you choose this path, you can ask for guidance on `#dev` channel on [Presto Community Slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html). However, I don't recommend reimplementing language layer -- this is expensive from time perspective.

I'd recommend translating your custom DSL into SQL either in your application or in some proxy in front of Presto. You can conveniently build proxy for Presto using [`presto-proxy`](https://github.com/prestosql/presto/tree/master/presto-proxy) as a base.

Comment: One more thing, if I want to extend Presto with UDF, it wouldn't be a problem, am I right?

Comment: It wouldn't. See docs for writing UDFs -- https://prestosql.io/docs/current/develop/functions.html. You can ask on `#dev` on https://prestosql.io/slack.html, shouldn't you need guidance.